# How to divide two values in influxdb flux query

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I have tried multiple variants of this query, but for some reason the last step doesn't work:

```
odds = from(bucket: "me")
  |> range(start: -1h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "games" and r["_field"] == "odds")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_value"] > 2.0)
  |> count()
  |> toFloat()
  |> last()

totalCount = from(bucket: "me")
  |> range(start: -1h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "games" and r["_field"] == "odds")
  |> count()
  |> toFloat()
  |> last()

percent = odds / totalCount * 100.0
```

It throws me error

> "stream[{A with _value: B, _value: float}] is not Divisible error"

I think I have some misconception about streams and data. I have tried adding/removing last(), tried to extract ._value, but so far with no luck.